# ElasticSearch - Cant not sort by distance location - "status": 500

Tags: elasticsearch

Target: search people and sort their name by the distance from their location to my location (input lat lon)

I input many rows of data like this :

```
{"index":{"_id":"1"}}
{"account_number":1,"location":[22.23, 23.12],"balance":39225,"firstname":"Amber","lastname":"Duke","age":32,"gender":"M","address":"880 Holmes Lane","employer":"Pyrami","email":"amberduke@pyrami.com","city":"Brogan","state":"IL"}
```

Notice the location here I input `"location":[22.23, 23.12]`

For simplicity, the below is the mapping of `firstname`, `lastname` and `location`

```
{
    "lat_lon_test2": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "firstname": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "lastname": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "location": {
                    "type": "float"
                },
  ..........................................
```

This my trial:

```
GET localhost:9200/lat_lon_test2/_search?pretty

{
    "query":
    {
        "multi_match": 
        {
            "fields":["firstname", "lastname"],
            "minimum_should_match": "80%",
            "query": "Hattie"
        }
    }
    ,
       "sort": [
    {
      "_geo_distance": {
        "location": [ 
          40.715,
          -73.998                          //my input location
        ],
        "order":         "asc",
        "unit":          "km", 
        "distance_type": "plane" 
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I got this result :

```
{
"error": {
    "root_cause": [
        {
            "type": "class_cast_exception",
            "reason": "class org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.plain.SortedNumericIndexFieldData cannot be cast to class org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexGeoPointFieldData (org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.plain.SortedNumericIndexFieldData and org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexGeoPointFieldData are in unnamed module of loader 'app')"
        }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
        {
            "shard": 0,
            "index": "lat_lon_test2",
            "node": "oyC0x3WNRC-3ok_TzAMT2w",
            "reason": {
                "type": "class_cast_exception",
                "reason": "class org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.plain.SortedNumericIndexFieldData cannot be cast to class org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexGeoPointFieldData (org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.plain.SortedNumericIndexFieldData and org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexGeoPointFieldData are in unnamed module of loader 'app')"
            }
        }
    ],
    "caused_by": {
        "type": "class_cast_exception",
        "reason": "class org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.plain.SortedNumericIndexFieldData cannot be cast to class org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexGeoPointFieldData (org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.plain.SortedNumericIndexFieldData and org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexGeoPointFieldData are in unnamed module of loader 'app')",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "class_cast_exception",
            "reason": "class org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.plain.SortedNumericIndexFieldData cannot be cast to class org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexGeoPointFieldData (org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.plain.SortedNumericIndexFieldData and org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexGeoPointFieldData are in unnamed module of loader 'app')"
        }
    }
},
"status": 500
```

}

I realise that I need to mapping location to `geopoint`

I did this:

```
PUT localhost:9200/lat_lon_test2/_mapping

{
    "properties": {
      "location": {
        "type": "geo_point"
      }
    }
}
```

I got this result:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "mapper [location] cannot be changed from type [float] to [geo_point]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "mapper [location] cannot be changed from type [float] to [geo_point]"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

My version: 7.9.3

Sorry for long post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the data-type of `location` from `float` to `geo_point` which is not possible, hence the exception, please create a new index with proper mapping and reindex all data according to the new data-type to fix the issue.

Please refer to the section on [update mapping of a field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#update-mapping) and what is covered and what is not covered, Also **If you need to change the mapping of a field in other indices, create a new index with the correct mapping and reindex your data into that index.**

Comment: About the logic of my `sort` above, is it correct ?